# uncheck all via script vs uncheck via mouse click

Tags: jquery

I have a script where each column in a table has a checkbox, if the checkbox is checked the column is hidden. This works fine if i physically with my mouse check the box. However, i am trying to implement a check/uncheck all script and whilst this appears to do what its suppose to do i.e. in the browser i can see all the column check boxes are checked and unchecked but the columns don't get hidden. They only get hidden if I manually uncheck each box.

**Here is the code responsible for hiding the columns**

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   var ColToHide = $(this).attr("name");    
    if(this.checked){
        $("td[class='" + ColToHide + "']").show();        
    }else{
        $("td[class='" + ColToHide + "']").hide();
    }

    $('div#Debug').text("hiding " + ColToHide);
});
```

**Here is the check/uncheck all script**

The html

```
<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>
```

The jquery

```
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event does not get fired when you set the `checked` state programmatically. To get around this you can raise the event manually, like this:

```
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).change();
});
```

Also note that you can shorten the logic in your `change()` handler by using `toggle`:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    $("td[class='" + this.name + "']").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: thanks Rory.. unfortunately the issue remains.. change event is not being fired off even though the boxes show as unchecked in the browser..

Comment: Could you please add the HTML of your table (or at least a small sample) to your question.

Comment: the html is being generated from a php script. here is an image of what the table looks like if it helps http://snag.gy/O2PYX.jpg

Comment: let me know if you still need to see what the HTML table looks like i could probably pastebin it even though its quite long

Comment: actually, after adding your changes I just noticed this warning in firebug: too much recursion
...b(a,b,d,e){var f,h,j,k,l,o,r,s,w,x;if((b?b.ownerDocument||b:v)!==n&&m(b),b=b||n,...

Comment: warning in chrome says; Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded